# How do I obtain a rolling buffer of the last two items emitted from a reactive stream?

Tags: operators, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a stream that emits numbers `x`. What I want is `dx` (difference in x) so I need a rolling buffer which emits `x_n` and `x_(n-1)` so I can map to `dx = x_n - x_(n-1)`. In a marble diagram this would look like ...

```
SOURCE --A------B------C--------D------F--G-----

RESULT ---------AB-----BC-------CD-----DF-FG----
```

This would be handy for other operations like rolling averages etc.

I have checked the [operator docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) but can't seem to find anything similar. `sample` is sort of close but is time dependent. `buffer` is also close but it strictly queues values with no overlap between the buffers.

I'm using RxJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RXJS 4**

You maybe don't even need a `buffer` for this, a simple `concatMap` might work for you (of course I don't know any details of your stream:

```
observable = Rx.Observable.from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]);

observable
  .bufferWithCount(2, 1)
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
});
```

See live [here](http://jsbin.com/rawulequno/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: That's a pretty interesting way of doing it - I did find a way which uses `bufferCount` which seems to be a RxJS only function not in the main reactive documents. I'll accept this but post mine as well.

Comment: Since there was no tag for [rxjs5] i assumed you where using version 4, and there is no `bufferCount` in rxjs4

Comment: Ah, well spotted!

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, and there is such an operator for rxjs4 - not that you'd need it now, but in case someone else uses RXJS4

Answer (score 5):

**RXJS 5**

RxJS has the [`bufferCount`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) operator which works as follows ...

```
observable = Rx.Observable.from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

bufferSize = 2
overlap = 1
observable.bufferCount(bufferSize, overlap)
    .subscribe(vals => console.log(vals));

// Results in,
//
// ["A", "B"]
// ["B", "C"]
// ...
```

`overlap` is actually the sample frequency so for example in the above case if `overlap = 2` then we would get the normal `buffer` behaviour.

Comment: Didn't know about `overlap`

Comment: @Bradford neither did I! The documentation makes it very easy to miss and with the myriad of operators it's easy to go off and expect something dedicated for this.

Comment: Note: This requires two items to have 'come in' before anything happens. If you're looking for something similar for a larger number of items (for example a recently viewed item list) this may be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911178/rxjs-take-n-last-elements-from-an-observable

Answer (score 3):

Two options that will work regardless of the version:

#### Better

**Pairwise**

```
Rx.Observable.from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
  .pairwise()
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```

**bufferCount** (or `bufferWithCount`)

This *does* exist in RxJS 4 as well as RxJS 5

> version == 5.* .* ===> `bufferCount`
>
> version >= 4.1.0 ===> `bufferCount`
>
> version < 4.1.0  ===> `bufferWithCount`

```
Rx.Observable.from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
  // Buffers of length 2 and skip 1 item (i.e. overlap)
  .bufferCount(2, 1)
  // the last buffer will have only the last item so drop it
  .filter(x => x.length == 2)
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```

See both [here](http://jsbin.com/gonagobuxu/1/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1):

```
observable = Rx.Observable.from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]);
```

we can do

```
observable
  .scan((x, y) => [_.last(x), y], [])
  .filter((x) => x[0] !== undefined)
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```

or if a hot observable:

```
observable.
  zip(observable.skip(1))
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```

or if a cold observable:

```
observable
  .publish(source_ => source_.zip(source_.skip(1)))
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```

or easiest:

```
observable
  .pairwise()
  .subscribe(all => {
    console.log(all);
  });
```