# RxJS - take n last elements from an observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

I want to take 3 last elements from an observable. Let's say that my timeline looks like this:

`--a---b-c---d---e---f-g-h-i------j->`

where: `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j are emitted values`

Whenever a new value is emitted I want to get it immediately, so it can look like this:

```
[a]
[a, b]
[a, b, c]
[b, c, d]
[c, d, e]
[d, e, f]
[e, f, g]
[f, g, h]
... and so on
```

I think that this is super useful. Imagine building a chat where you want to display 10 last messages. Whenever a new message comes you want to update your view.

My attempt: [demo](http://jsbin.com/bumolukoye/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `scan` for this:

```
from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'])
  .pipe(
    scan((acc, val) => {
      acc.push(val);
      return acc.slice(-3);
    }, []),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This will print:

```
[ 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
[ 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
...
[ 's', 't', 'u' ]
```

The `bufferCount` won't do what you want. It'll emit only when each buffer is exactly `=== 3` which means you won't get any emission until you post at least 3 messages.

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: Upvote for correct answer. I have a bit another with low case

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what I wanted to achieve

Comment: very clever! Any idea why this isn't a built in operator? I must just be hitting all the uncommon use cases for RxJs because I keep looking for things like this that aren't already built in.

Comment: how to convert this to a reusable operator?

Comment: Won't the accumulated array just keep growing though? Seems like a memory leak.

Comment: This is a great answer, but a more succinct and functional version could use

```scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val].slice(-3), [])```

Comment: @adam0101 no, it won't. The accumulator array will never grow past size 4. What you return from the scan function is what gets passed as the `acc` parameter on the next run. So for a run when it's already size 3, it will `.push(val)` making it size 4, then it will get cut down to size 3 again via `.slice(-3)`. It's not leaking.

Comment: I'd inverse the order of pushing and slicing, otherwise you will mutate data that's already leaked to the outside (the accumulator)

Answer (score 5):

You can look at [**Observable#bufferCount**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) function. One difference is that it wants at least 3 times to emit (first parameter, in this example).

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const example = source.bufferCount(3,1)
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just like @martin has mentioned, bufferCount emits only when each buffer is exactly === 3

Comment: Thanks. I have also mentioned it

Comment: You can do `source.next(null); source.next(null); source.next(null);` [sic]